# Cancellation Property of Diagram of Unramified and Smooth Morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is [Vakil 21.6 G b)](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf), self-study. We have to show that given locally finite type morphisms of schemes $\pi: X \to Y$ and $\rho: Y \to Z$, if $\tau = \rho \circ \pi$ is smooth of relative dimension $n$ and $\rho$ is umramified, then $\pi$ is smooth of relative dimension $n$. Here is what I have observed:

By the Cancellation Theorem 10.1.9 applied to $P$ being the property "smooth," $\pi$ is smooth of some relative dimension since the diagonal map $\delta_{\rho}$ is always locally closed and locally closed embeddings are always smooth of some relative dimension. We need this dimension to be $n$.

I believe we need to show the cotangent sheaf $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is locally free of rank $n$. We know that $\Omega_{X/Z}$ is locally free of rank $n$ and that $\Omega_{Y/Z}$ is $0$, both by assumption. I would like to use to cotangent sequence

$$\pi^* \Omega_{Y/Z} \to \Omega_{X/Z} \to \Omega_{X/Y} \to 0$$

but I cannot guarantee the left term is $0$ just because $\Omega_{Y/Z} = 0$ (I don't think). Even if I could, Vakil's hint is to use the previous problem where we showed a morphism is unramified iff its diagonal is an open immersion, but I do not see how to use that. For what it's worth, this problem is labeled "Easy Exercise," so I think I am overcomplicating this.